# Displaying a form when no model is present

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The application I'm working on has a feature where the user can click on a link to send an email to a friend. I do not want to save the friend information (first, last, email), so I tried doing the following (in users_controller.rb):

```
def send_invitation_to_friend
  if params[:commit] == 'Email Invitation'
    @friend_info = params[:friend_info]
    EventMailer.deliver_send_invitation_to_friend(@friend_info).deliver
    redirect_to_root_url
  end
  render 'send_invitation_to_friend'
end
```

and in my views/users/send_invitation_to_friend_html.erb, I have:

```
<div class="pagetopper"></div>

  <% if !user_signed_in? %>
    <% redirect_to_root_url %>
  <% end %>

<%= form_for @friend_info, :url => {:controller => :users, :action => :send_invitation_to_friend} do |f| %>

  <div class="field-section-header">
     About The Person You're Inviting
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="control-label"><%= f.label :first, FIRST_STR %></div>
    <div class="controls"><%= f.text_field :first, :class => "request-text-line" %></div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="control-label"><%= f.label :last, LAST_STR %></div>
    <div class="controls"><%= f.text_field :last, :class => "request-text-line" %></div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="control-label"><%= f.label :email, EMAIL_STR %></div>
    <div class="controls"><%= f.email_field :email, :class => "request-text-line" %></div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls"><%= submit_tag 'Email Invitation', :class => "submit_button" %></div>
  </div>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Extracted source (around line #7):

4:     <% redirect_to_root_url %>
5: <% end %>
6: 
7: <%= form_for @friend_info, :url => {:controller => :users, :action => :send_invitation_to_friend} do |f| %>
```

I don't have a model and a migration for friend_info because I don't want to save this information, so how I display the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

form_for is used for model update/creation. In your case you can use form_tag as,

```
<%= form_tag( {:controller => :users, :action => :send_invitation_to_friend} ) do  %>
 <div class="control-group">
  <div class="control-label"><%= label_tag :first, FIRST_STR %></div>
  <div class="controls"><%= text_field_tag :first, :class => "request-text-line" %></div>
      ...
```

you can find more on form_tag at http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag